# How can I remove an unfinished java installation installed via terminal?

Tags: java

Well, since I was so stupid to install the java via terminal with official package, it stuck on the licence agreement screen, because I had to accept it, but no key from my keyboard worked to accept. So I've closed the terminal, killing my install. Now it says in newly opened terminal java is installed, but does not display in software center. The problem is, I want to uninstall it to get to the software center one.

Some more info: 
Why do I want java actually? Because I recently upgraded my graphicscard from onboard to radeon. So, my MineCraft would actually load up, but as soon as it has to load a map, it crashes. I looked in the log file it leaves behind, I don´t see any issues with my graphics, it says there is something wrong with my java. Can´t post output here because I've deleted the files. Since java isn´t working, I cannot create a new one. On my onboard card it worked, but it doesn't play good because that thing came out of '06. So since I've installed my official radeon drivers and plugged in my card it stopped working. My graphicscard isn´t broken too, because it still worked in Win 7. I had working the openjdk runtime 6 (which I meant in previous part too) on my onboard. I had to uninstall that, and install the official, which I think was the most worse choice, because I also could have reinstalled runtime 6 or even 7 from software center. 
Maybe the output from java -version could be handy:

```
java version "1.6.0_23" 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.2)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode, sharing)
```

So, how could I uninstall an unfinished! install of java via terminal?

If needing more info, just ask for it!

Comment: what command did you use to install it?

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-software-properties,
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java,
sudo apt-get update,
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-plugin,

those come from this site: http://superuser.com/questions/353983/how-do-i-install-the-sun-java-sdk-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneric

Comment: try Ubuntu software center again to install if they say something about broken package try synaptic software manager under filter select broke and remove those packages in red then try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've installed the packages: `sun-java6-jdk` and  `sun-java6-plugin`. to remove them just type:

- `sudo apt-get purge sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-plugin`

if you want to install them again, then just type

- `sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-plugin`

*the `purge` command removes everything there is and clear all config files of those programs, so if you have a broken install a `purge` + a new `install` is recommended.*

Comment: Ok Thanks man will try :)

I am very sorry but this doesn´t work for me. These are both commands and output:


sudo apt-get purge sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-plugin
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

What to do now?

Comment: @Remy do you have like update manager running? or Ubuntu Software center? try to reboot then try again.

Comment: Well, I discovered I just had to install again, not even removing. This because it didn´t detect any java while deleting. So now I installed it again, and found out I had to move with my arrow keys to select the OK button to accept. Now it is installed and I could Run the game again, but still as soon it has loaded a map, it crashes. Meaning minecraft right now. So my actual problem isn´t solved yet. I thought I had to reinstall java, but yeah, that didn´t help. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: is it crashing when you start the game or is it after like 5, 10 minutes of playing? what graphics do you have it set for? is your hardware good enough?

Comment: Well, it crashes not after a certain time, but after I load the map. I mean, the game starts fine, but I don´t get to the playable map. So, as soon the green line reaches the other side, my game crashes. My hardware is also good enough, because I have played it on lowest settings but still really good on my Win 7.

Also, on my onboard card it worked with lowest settigs and like 10 fps, but still worked. Now it doesn´t.

Comment: so even if you start it with the lowest settings and start a new map, the game crashes? tips, reinstall java, get a new version of minecraft, delete the old one.

Comment: Actually, everything is up to date. I have my java reinstalled, minecraft is the latest version.

Comment: well, the latest version isn't a fresh version. if you download a new version you will know if it's a problem on your end (software), but you will still don't know if it's a global problem with java or minecraft. And you will still don't know if it's because of your hardware.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the late comment. I've fixed it (actually, haven't fixed anything, but just the last try worked). So, I think my map was just corrupt, but multiplayer worked fine. Strange...